# For which $x$ does the series converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For which $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is the series defined:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \cos(nx)$?

I've tried alternating series test and ratio test but it got me nowhere. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try the absolute convergence test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and set $a_{n}=\frac{(-1)^n \cos(nx)}{n^2}$. Note $|a_n| \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Can you take is from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left| \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \cos(nx)\right| \le \frac 1 {n^2}
$$